# Retrieve historical data with Fiware Orion/Cygnus

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I have a Fiware Orion installed with a Cygnus sink and a mongoDB back-end.
What is a common method to retrieve the history of the data points stored in mongoDB? Can I do that using Cygnus?

The API of Cygnus doesn't give anything to retrieve the data:
http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cygnus-common/installation_and_administration_guide/management_interface_v1/index.html

I would like to have some api endpoints for historical data:
`api/v1/history/entities...`

Answer (score 1):

Cygnus sinks for MongoDB (there are 2 sinks, one for raw data - I guess it is the one you are using -, and another one for aggregated data) are aligned with [STH Comet](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-sth-comet) and its [API](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-sth-comet#api-walkthrough).

Cygnus only provides a managemet API since it is the tool in charge of putting Orion context data in MongoDB (or HDFS, MySQL, Carto, CKAN...). Once persisted the data in the persistence backend, it up to the persistence backend to provide means for its data exploitation; or it is up to some tool wrapping the persistence backend native API, as STH Comet API does.